# Any reason to have a session ID within a form?

Tags: php, asp.net, django, session

is there any reason for me to place the session ID within a form,
as a hidden form field?

---

**Thank you everyone!! :)**

Comment: Php will do this for you if `session.use_trans_sid` is true, I believe asp.net can be configured to handle this for you also.

Comment: Is there any reason for me to attach a yellow flag to the antenna on my car? Possibly, but how would you know? You might want to tell us why you are *considering* "placing the session ID within a form" ;)

Comment: @Jorn: I'm not considering placing it, I have noticed developers use it. And it isn't really as random as a yellow flag on the car antenna. A session ID within a field could have some generally accepted uses.

Comment: Well, you could have told us that from the start and provided a link to a site that displays the described behavior :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a part of one of the possible methods for preventing against [cross-site request forgery](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) attacks.

It can be used in the [Synchronizer Token Pattern](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

It can also be used in the "Double-Submit Cookies" method mentioned at the bottom of the page linked to above.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason would be to maintain session state for all users including the ones that have disabled cookies.